# Does an update have to be different to an insert when uploading a file?

Tags: php, mysqli, image-uploading

I'm having a problem with the update section of a CRUD I'm making. The create works fine, and I'm using very similar code for the update but there's something going wrong and it seems to be a problem with the file upload.

I have a page that displays all the rows from the database. There's a link next to each row that says edit and when that's clicked on, it goes to a page that displays the row from the Db in a form. The information can then be changed and there's a submit button that when clicked makes the action of the form run, which is a php file that has this:

```
<?php
include ('includes/DbCon.php');

if (isset($_POST['ud_id']))$id = $_POST['ud_id'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE id = '$id'";
$result = $mysqli->query ($query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>=1)
{
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH);
    $headline = $row['headline'];
    $body = $row['body'];
    $image = $row['image'];
}
else{
    $mysqli->error;
}


//Set directory etc for image upload
$target_dir = "images/photo/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["ud_image"]["name"]);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["ud_image"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)or die($mysqli->error))
{
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'alert("News Items Saved")';
    echo '</script>';
} else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error with your file.";
}
```

There's more to it but it doesn't get past this, so I need help figuring out what's wrong with it. I've used var_dump and also printed the variables to see what's getting passed and everything is fine until it get's to the $target_file. When I print that variable I get 'image/photo' but I suspect it should be the full file name as well as the target path.

It's set the same way as the insert code, so I don't know what's wrong with it.

As requested, here's the form:

```
<form action="update.php" method="post" class="newNews">

<input type="hidden" name="ud_id" value="<?=$id;?>">

<label for="title">Title</label><br />
<input type="text" name="ud_headline" value="<?=$headline;?>"/>

<label for="text">Body</label><br />
<textarea name="ud_body" rows="5" cols="21" value="" class="editBody"><?=$body;?></textarea>

<p>Current Photo</p>
<img src="images/photo/<?=$image?>" alt=" " width="auto" height="auto"><br />           

<input type="file" name="ud_image" class="newsImage" ><br />

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update news item" class='addNew' />

</form>
```

Comment: can you show us the form code??

Comment: Form added to the question. Might it be because it doesn't have the enctype set?

Comment: What again is the actual sql error if any?

Comment: @tdrsam did you try with enctype="multipart/form-data" ??

Comment: I just added the enctype and that's gotten the image uploading, but the update is not actually saving the strings to the Db. The query is this: `$edit = mysqli_query($mysqli,"UPDATE news SET headline='$ud_headline', body='$ud_body', image='$ud_image' WHERE id='$id'");`

Comment: You don't even know if it is getting to the update statement

Comment: I used a var_dump to check what was in the variables and it seemed ok.

Comment: We don't know if you have mysqli error reporting enabled

Comment: Vardump it for us! Plus that is seen no where in your code u shared.

Comment: Dumping the vars is one thing. Getting as far as the update stmt and dumping that string is another

Comment: This is an example of one of the 3 variables I have which are all set out the same way: `if (isset($_POST['ud_body']))$body = $_POST['ud_body'];` It goes from the image upload to the variables to the update statement and the var_dump contains the correct values.

Comment: Like i said show a dump of the actual update stmt string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81487/discussion-between-tdrsam-and-drew-pierce).

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a problem with your `move_uploaded_file()` function. From the online manual:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Try this code:

```
<?php
...
if ($_FILES["ud_image"]["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
{
    $tmp_name = $_FILES["ud_image"]["tmp_name"];
    $name = $_FILES["ud_image"]["name"];
    if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$target_dir$name"))
    {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'alert("News Items Saved")';
        echo '</script>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error with your file.";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Sorry, there was an error with your file.";
}
```

Comment: That's gotten the file upload working - the file is being stored in the target directory. But, the row in the database is not updating.